# After Effects - How do I create animated coding

Tags: after-effects

Are there any tutorials on how to create animated 'coding', where it looks like code is being typed in? I want to do something similar to this: http://footage.shutterstock.com/clip-1355773-stock-footage-a-d-animation-about-the-network-data-flow.html. In that video about half way through it pans to a section where it looks like code is being typed in.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any tutorials off hand (you will need to do a google) but to animate text to make it look as if its typing on isnt too hard:

1. Create your text layer
2. Expand the later (clicking the white triangle next to the name)
3. Click on the animate button > select Opacity
4. Now you can use the range selectors to animate what is changed.

There is also a typewriter preset in the Effects and Presets panel which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's some text animation effects you can use to automate it.
This tutorial http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/text_blur_titles/ uses the text animation blur, one of the others is text typing.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you are after, but the simplest way could be to use a screen recording tool to record you typing the code. Have a look at [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/4096/674) for guidance - it is very easy to do, and you can time it as you like, rather than have to worry about setting animation schedules etc.